# Closest assembly related to python bytecode

Tags: python, assembly, bytecode, pyc

I have the following basic python function:

```
def squared(num):
    if num < 2:
        print ('OK!')
    return num * num
```

Which produces the following bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(squared)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('OK!')
             15 PRINT_ITEM          
             16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             17 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 20)

  4     >>   20 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
             23 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
             26 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

Most of the above look like `mov` and `jmp`-type operators. However, what do the following most closely mean in assembly?

`LOAD_FAST`, `LOAD_CONST` ?

What might be the closest assembly instructions for this?

Comment: `LOAD_FAST` is accessing a local variable - this would be a move from a memory location (relative to the stack frame pointer), or possibly a move from a register (depending on the platform's standards, and the number of locals vs. the number of available registers).  `LOAD_CONST` would generally be a move of a constant value.  But note that trying to find a one-to-one equivalence between a high-level bytecode and an assembly language isn't going to get you very far: `PRINT_ITEM`, for example, is not something you're going to find as a single assembly opcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's bytecode is for a stack-based VM to simplify interpreters and waste less space on addresses (e.g. register numbers) by making them implicit.  Loads are pushing onto that stack.

If you transliterated this in a very literal and braindead manner to an asm equivalent for fixed-width integers (unlike Python arbitrary precision integers), every LOAD_FAST might be a load from a local variable (in memory on the stack) into a register.  But you'd still have to choose which registers, and real ISAs have a limited number of registers.  But yes, LOAD_FAST is like a load.

Of course if you weren't intentionally being literal just for the sake of it, you'd know you already had `num` in a register and not load it again.  So you'd use an instruction that read the same register twice, like `imul eax, eax`

And you'd have local variables living in registers when possible, not spilling them to the stack in the first place until you run out of registers.

---

If you want to learn about asm for CPUs, you can write an equivalent function in C and compile it (with optimization enabled, at least `-Og` if not `-O2` or `-O3`) on the Godbolt compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/.  Or on your desktop, but Matt Godbolt wrote some nice filtering to remove noise and leave only the interesting parts.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

Comment: Well, actually you can't easily do any of these transformations as Python is too dynamic. `num` can be object of any type so you can't just load its value into a register and then use a multiply instruction.  If this were Python 3 you couldn't even assume that `print` was the builtin `print` function.  It's hard to convert Python into assembly without essentially just unrolling the interpreter loop.

Comment: @RossRidge: Good point.  I was imagining a translation that was real Python, treating `num` as a fixed-width integer, and was just doing the math parts.  Probably should have just stuck to human-created analogy instead of bringing up compilers, but I wanted to say something about how braindead and literal the translation / transliteration was.

Comment: @RossRidge: updated to remove discussion of "compiling", and just talk about hand-crafted analogies, not implementing real Python.

Comment: @PeterCordes how does that eventually get compiled to bytecode? Is that also part of CPython, or does that happen somewhere else, for example with a gcc or something else?

Comment: @David542: How does what get compiled to bytecode?  I'm talking about writing (by hand in assembly) a function that takes an `int` arg and returns the square.  (And mostly ignoring the part about I/O.)  i.e. writing a function that does something similar to what the Python function does.  Your question isn't very answerable, but I wanted to say something and this was too long for a comment.